# apache .htaccess redirect 301 old domain to new domain with page name changes as well

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am just working out the server configuration for a new version of an existing site.

There was two previous sites that are being merged into one:
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com

These are being merged in to www.domain2.com.

The DNS entry for www.domain2.com will be changed to point at the same ip address as www.domain2.com.

Page addresses have changed so there is not a one to one mapping from the old pages to the new pages.

I need to redirect the pages from both of the old sites to the new sites. So that is:

1. pages from domain1.com to domain2.com AND with the changed page
   addresses.
2. old pages from domain2.com to new pages with different addresses.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect from the domain1.com to domain2.com by doing this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

However, for redirecting old pages to new ones, only you will know what to do, you will have to write RewriteRules depending on the cases you have.

For more informations about Rewriting, [see documentation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)